# show $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i\bar{y_i}$ is defined

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I need to show that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i\bar{y_i}$ is defined if $\sum_{i=1}^\infty x_i $ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty y_i$ are convergent.

this is my solution:
since $\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i$ converges then the sequence of partial sums converges as well:
$lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i=c<\infty$.
Hence, the product of two converging limits are convergent: $lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i*lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i=c*c=c^2$

then I want to use the Cauchy-Scwartz inequality to show that my original sum converges. The problem I don't know how to put the modules into the picture. 
this is the inequality I am referring to:
$\left| \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \bar{y}_i \right|^2 \leq \sum_{j=1}^n |x_j|^2 \sum_{k=1}^n |y_k|^2 .$

Comment: Don't you want $\sum_{i=1}^\infty$? These sums are always defined for $N$.

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conclusion to your problem is not true. Take, for example, $\sum_nx_n=\sum_ny_n=\sum_n\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ which are convergent, while $\sum_nx_ny_n=\sum_n\frac{1}{n}$ is divergent.

If your series are absolute convergent then the result is correct since, for every $n$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k||y_k|\le\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|x_k|\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^n|y_k|\right)
$$

Comment: Square summability would be enough, which is weaker than absolute convergence.